# Can't sign into android

Tags: google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow, google-account

Few days ago i updated my Samsung galaxy j5 into marshmallow version & now I'm unable to sign into google account, it gives an error
- "Sorry, there seems to be a problem. please try again"

I've tried hard reset, factory reset, other gmail accounts but i always get same error again & again. Please help me

Comment: Logcat output might help here.  You could also try flashing OpenGApps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you sign into the other Google Account?

If do, your google account is wrong
but If not, maybe I guess, your phone is crashed (such as /system) while android updating.
-> You should go to Samsung A/S center

If I have wrong thinking, Point out please